# In Maple, how does one specify ranges for x,y, and t when using plot3d to plot a combination of parametric and Cartesian coordinate surfaces?

Tags: maple

Let's say I have a function $f(x,y) = 3x^2 + 5xy +2y^2$, a parametric line $ \langle 1+t, 2 - \frac{16t}{13}, 21 \rangle$, and a plane $z = f(x,y) = 21$, and I plot them:

```
f := (x, y) -> 3*x^2 + 5*y*x + 2*y^2
line := [1 + t, 2 - (16*t)/13, 21]
plot3d([21, line, f])
```

The docs for `plot3d` tell us:

> The plot3d command computes the plot of a three-dimensional surface. The first two calling sequences describe surface plots in Cartesian coordinates, while the second two describe parametric surface plots.

I did not see examples of mixing up parametric with surface plots in Cartesian coordinates as I have above. The commands above work, but my question is how do I specify ranges for x, y, and t?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a book called "Understanding Maple", section 6.5 called "Combining Plots".

```
f := (x, y) -> 3*x^2 + 5*y*x + 2*y^2
line := [1 + t, 2 - (16*t)/13, 21]
plot3d([21, line, f])
with(plots):
p1 := plot3d(f):
p2 := plot3d(line):
p3 := plot3d(21):
display([p1, p2, p3])
```

`display` command, part of the `plots` package, is can be used to display two or  more curves that use different coordinate systems. Note that in specifying $p1$ and $p2$ we can provide any options we want to customize those specific graphs, including specifying ranges for their variables.

You can also specify a "view" option on `display` to control the range displayed.